# Can we derive a formula to calculate pointwise confidence intervals for empirical distribution functions via subsampling?

Tags: probability, statistics, hypergeometric-function, confidence-interval

I am trying to derive a formula to calculate pointwise confidence intervals for empirical distribution functions using [Hartigan's subsampling approach](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1969.10501057). The main idea is similar to bootstrapping, but does not involve resampling with replacement. It simply uses all non-empty subsamples to compute confidence intervals and/or estimate variances.

Assume that we have $N \in \mathbb{N}$ realizations, say $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_N$, where we assign indices so that $X_i \leq X_j$ whenever $i \leq j$. We want to compute the subsampling confidence interval for $\hat{F}(X_K)$, which is the value the empirical distribution function attains at point $X_K$. To achieve this, we need the subsampling CDF for $\hat{F}(X_K)$. It is not obvious what this CDF looks like, but it is relatively easy to state the subsampling PMF:

$$
p(x)= \frac{1}{2^N - 1} \;\; \cdot \sum_{(k, n) \, \in \, \mathcal{X}(x)} {K \choose k} {N - K \choose n - k}
$$
where
$$\mathcal{X}(x) = \lbrace (k, n) \in \mathbb{N}^2 : \frac{k}{n} = x \, \text{ and } \, 0 \leq n - k \leq N - K \, \text{ and } \, k \leq K \rbrace,
$$
with the implication that $p(x) = 0$ if $\mathcal{X}(x)$ is empty. The next step is to derive a closed-form expression for the subsampling CDF from the PMF, but I failed to do this. Can we derive a closed-form expression for the subsampling CDF?

*Note:*

The summand is equal to the unnormalized hypergeometric PMF. The key difference is that this PMF aggregates (i.e. sums) configurations with the same success ratio.

**Update:**

I was able to obtain the following explicit formula for the PMF:
$$
p \left( \frac{a}{b} \right) = \frac{1}{2^N - 1} \;\; \cdot \sum^{M(a, \, b)}_{i = 1} {K \choose a \cdot i} {N - K \choose (b - a) \cdot i}
$$
where
$$M(a, b) = \begin{cases} \left \lfloor \frac{K}{a} \right \rfloor & \frac{a}{b} \geq \frac{K}{N} \, , \\ \\ \left \lfloor \frac{N - K}{b - a} \right \rfloor & \text{otherwise} \, , \end{cases}
$$
for any coprime $(a, b) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ with $N \geq b \geq a \leq K$ and $b \neq 0$. Again, the sum is implicitly taken to be zero whenever $M(a, b) < 1$.

Applying several algebraic transformations involving Pochhammer symbols, this expression further simplifies into:
$$
p \left( \frac{a}{b} \right) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{2^K - 1}{2^N - 1} & \frac{a}{b} = 1 \, , \\ \\ \dfrac{{}_b F_{b - 1}\left(\alpha \,; \beta \,; (-1)^b\right) - 1}{2^N - 1} & \text{otherwise} \, , \end{cases}
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha &= \left \lbrace 1 - \frac{K + i}{a} : i \in \lbrace 1, 2, \cdots, a \rbrace \right \rbrace \cup \left \lbrace \frac{K + i - N}{b - a} : i \in \lbrace 0, 1, \cdots, b - a - 1 \rbrace \right \rbrace \, , \\
\beta &= \left \lbrace \frac{i}{a} : i \in \lbrace 1, 2, \cdots, a \rbrace \right \rbrace \cup \left \lbrace \frac{i}{b - a} : i \in \lbrace 1, 2, \cdots, b - a - 1 \rbrace \right \rbrace
\end{align}
$$
with ${}_p F_q$ denoting the generalized hypergeometric function. Again, this expression is valid only for coprime $(a, b) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ that satisfy $a \leq K$ and $b - a \leq N - K$.

However, I am currently not able to simplify this formula further or use it to derive a closed-form expression for the subsampling CDF.

*Example:*

If we choose $N = 7$ and $K = 5$, the feasible success ratios are:
$$
\left \lbrace 0, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{5}{7}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{4}{5}, \frac{5}{6}, 1 \right \rbrace \, .
$$
Probabilities of these ratios are:
$$
\left \lbrace \frac{3}{127},\frac{5}{127},\frac{20}{127},\frac{10}{127},\frac{25}{127},\frac{1}{127},\frac{20}{127},\frac{10}{127},\frac{2}{127},\frac{31}{127} \right \rbrace \, .
$$

I tried consulting a few on-line resources such as OEIS to see whether these numbers belong to a well-known pattern, but was not successful.